# jQuery Ajax Override the fail method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to override the fail method as below, but it trigger both the fail methods.

And im getting 2 alerts "alert 1" &  "override fail"

Is it able to get only the "override fail" alert.

```
   var jqxhr = $.ajax("example.php")
       .done(function () {
       alert("success");
   })
       .fail(function () {
       alert("alert 1");
   });

   jqxhr.fail(function () {
       alert("override fail");
   });
```

Comment: the jqxhr variable was defined in a framework level js which i cant modify and i just to override the same ...is there anyway to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your fail callback call another function.

```
var failCallback = function () {
    alert("alert 1");
};

var jqxhr = $.ajax("example.php")
    .done(function () {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        failCallback();
    });

// change the function stored in failCallback var
failCallback = function () {
    alert("override fail");
};
```

Now, your fail callback will call the function stored in failCallback variable.

I don't know whay you want to do this. But this works, if the only thing you want is override the callback behavior.